# Windows Phone 8.1 WinJS AppBar disappears when navigating to another page containing an AppBar

Tags: winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I have two Pivot pages each with their own unique AppBar. The second pivot page, is accessible through the first pivot page via the AppBar. However, when I visit the second pivot page, its corresponding AppBar is not there. At first I thought the AppBar was not being rendered, but I suspect that it is being rendered, and being hidden. Furthermore, when I press the back button, the AppBar corresponding the first page is also gone.

I've attempted doing the following in the ready block

`WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function() {
  /* Grab winControl for app bar, and show it */
})`

But that didn't work. What is going on?

Comment: Ah, I am not the only one; here is the issue: https://github.com/winjs/winjs/issues/140

Comment: easiest solution is to define the appBar in the default page and then turn on/off buttons programatically. seems like a bug :(

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you need to give the appBar a different identifiers (`id` option of your appBar div tag) in everyone of your HTML pages.

P.S: don't forget to update `id` in your related JS code.